# Laravel eloquent relationship user id issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I currently have many tables but for simplicity i am going to show the two affected ones. They consist of:

- Users
- Announces

One user can have many announces and one announce only belongs to one user. It seems like a Many to One Relationship (or so i think).

Schema creation for database:

```
Schema::create('X_USER', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('X_ANNOUNCE', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {           
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('X_USER')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now the models are also quite simple I have this on **User** model:

```
public function announces()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Announce', 'created_by');
}
```

And this on the **Announce** Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by');
}
```

When I insert an announce i do the following on my laravel AnnounceController.php (store function):

```
$announce = Announce::create($request->all());

return Response::json([
            'message' => 'Announce Created Succesfully',
            'data' => $this->transform($announce)
    ]);
```

This previous line actually inserts everything in database correctly. Nothing wrong so far until I do the "transform" that returns the json in the format I would want to pass to the frontend:

```
private function transform($announce)
{
    //Get User
    $user = Announce::find($announce['created_by'])->user;

    return [
           'announce_id'            => $announce['id'],
           'announce_title'         => $announce['title'],
           'announce_user_id'       => $user->id,
           'announce_created_by'    => $user->name,
        ];
}
```

When I do `$user = Announce::find($announce['created_by'])->user` I never get the correct id ($user->id). However, $user->id and $user->name are coherent, just not the correct ones. I have checked that the id ($announce['created_by']) is correct as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I understand that this question is not the best asked question but I am going sort of nuts after trying for way too many hours, checking stack and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `find` method you are searching by id, and I assume, the correct way would be:

```
$user = Announce::where('created_by', $announce['created_by'])->first()->user;
```

But in fact it does not make much sense here I think, because for `transform` method it should be enough to use code like this:

Also you should be able to use code like this for `tranform` method:

```
private function transform($announce)
{
    return [
           'announce_id'            => $announce->id,
           'announce_title'         => $announce->title,
           'announce_user_id'       => $announce->user->id,
           'announce_created_by'    => $announce->user->name,
        ];
}
```

Comment: On your first suggestion I got **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$user**.

On the second I got **Trying to get property of non-object**.

Seems like not working for now, thanks for the tips though

Comment: @Xelnag I've updated first way but it won't probably work this way. And in second example, you should make sure you have user set for each announce, for example instead of `$announce->user->id` you can use `$announce->user ? $announce->user->id : 'no user'` and same for name

Comment: I have tried the first one now and actually works, however I still do not understand why is it returning a collection of users instead of the single user which matches the "id" if I do not use the `->first()` function. For the second one, just does not work, I made sure all of them were not empty and even putting that inline IF did not work either.